# Populating a select menu based off of previously chosen select menu in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, knockout.js, data-binding

I've searched high and low and haven't quite found an answer that answers my question so I hope that it's okay that I ask.

I'm learning Knockout JS and I'm trying to use it in a Wordpress plugin. I'm attempting to pull data from an external API and then populate a `<select>` menu based on that data.

That's working perfectly, but the issue I'm running into is populating a *second* `<select>` menu with the previously selected object's `pricing_parameters`.

From what I gather, I can set the  `optionsValue` to one of the object's properties such as `serviceId` or `serviceName`. I tried setting it `serviceParams` but that returns `[object Object]`.

Furthermore, wouldn't this disallow me from displaying the `serviceName` of the first `<option>` selected? If so, what is the proper way of handling this information so that it can be used in multiple areas?

Here is an example response: (JSFiddle below it)

```
{"services":[{
  "id":1,
  "code":"A",
  "name":"Service 1",
  "price":110.0,
  "hourly":false,
  "maids_minimum":1,
  "maids_maximum":1,
  "hours_minimum":1,
  "hours_maximum":1,
  "extras":[{
    "id":1,"name":"Extra 1","price":10.0,"quantity_based":true
  },{
    "id":2,"name":"Extra 2","price":20.0,"quantity_based":false
  }],
  "pricing_parameters":[{
    "id":1,"name":"Example pricing parameter","price":12.0,"quantity_minimum":1,"quantity_maximum":3
  }]
},{
  "id":2,
  "code":"B",
  "name":"Service 2",
  "price":35.0,
  "hourly":true,
  "maids_minimum":1,
  "maids_maximum":3,
  "hours_minimum":2,
  "hours_maximum":4,
  "extras":[],
  "pricing_parameters":[]
}]}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuvj816L/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just a couple of things here, 1) you are setting the optionsValue to the service Id that makes the framework pass just the id to the selectedService observable 2) if you have the "with" scope set up there is no need to reference it  again with in that scope and 3) the select tag had  no matching tag

```
<select class="form-control" id="bedrooms" data-bind="options: services, optionsText: 'serviceName', value: serviceSelected, event:{change: logIt}">
</select>
<!-- ko with: serviceSelected-->
    <select class="form-control" data-bind="optionsText: 'name',options:serviceParameters"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

made the changes in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/59hca470/1/

Comment: Wow, that was so simple, I can't believe it. I spent hours on this! If possible, can you elaborate on #2? I'm not sure if I follow.

Comment: Glad I could help ... so in your fiddle I saw that you said "<!-- ko with: serviceSelected()--> " ... so any data binding with in that scope (between <ko>...</ko> will access observables on the serviceSelected directly so you don't have say "serviceSelected().serviceParameters" . The framework would interpret this as "serviceSelected.serviceSelected().serviceParameters" does that make sense?

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Since I'm pairing the select with serviceSelected, the rest is implied. Gosh, you're such a life saver!